# Magento community gift card extension?

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions, free-gift

I need to invent gift cards as products in my store. I realized that you can do this in Magento Go,

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-gift-card

What about Magento Community version? Can I invent gift cards in this version?

I have seen there are a lot gift card extensions, but they all needed to be paid. Just wonder if any **free** gift card extensions around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+gift+card+extension+free](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento%20gift%20card%20extension%20free)
And here is one I found on a simple search. I haven't used it, but, like you asked, it is free.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/devsters-gift-cards.html

I know you may not want to use a paid extension but I can recommend you this one http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/unirgy-giftcert.html. I've used it in the past and it's worth the money.
I'm in no way associated with the extension provider. I just used it and liked it.

Comment: One thing to note with Unirgy though is that you're required to install IonCube which Unirgy uses to obfuscate their code, I've always found that a little annoying (code obfuscation for an extension built for an open source platform)

Comment: @moose. Oh. I didn't know that. When I used their extension a long time ago the code was not obfuscated. I will stop recommending this extension from now on if that is the case.

Comment: Devsters_Gift_Cards has a bug I think - you get shipping method options on your cart and checkout page, which it should not be there in the first first because the gift card is non ship-able product.

Answer (score 1):

New Best Free Gift Card extension :
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/kartparadigm-giftcard.html